# Connecting wireless keyboard to a device that lacks bluetooth?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, bluetooth

I have an odd problem that I'm wondering if you can help with.

I have a wireless keyboard (Arteck HB030B) that connects via Bluetooth. I want to connect it to an old laptop that doesn't have Bluetooth. Is this possible, and if so what is the best way to do it please?

The keyboard is compatible with the laptop's operating system (Windows 10). The laptop has usb ports but no micro usb ports; the keyboard has a micro usb for charging.

Is there a way to connect usb to micro usb remotely? Or to enable Bluetooth via plugging in some kind of usb dongle? Google is inconclusive.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: USB Bluetooth dongles are small and cheap. I assume you don't find anything because most people just buy and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bluetooth USB-A dongles exist, and are pretty cheap: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=bluetooth+usb+dongle

This should give your laptop bluetooth, and allow you to connect to BT devices.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the answer!